# Update form entry using the Guest Entries plugin

Tags: form, saveentry, plugin-guestentries

I am trying to create a form that anyone can submit regardless if they are logged in or not. I found the Pixel & Tonic [Guest Entries](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries) plugin for this.
Now that I've installed and configured the plugin updating entries doesn't work. Whenever I want to update an entry a new one is created instead.

Here is the code I use:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="loginForm">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}    

    <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="88">        

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="guestEntries/saveEntry">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="entryform?hash={{ hash }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="title" />

    <label for="text-naamSite">Wat is de naam van uw organisatie/onderneming?</label>
    <input type="text" id="text-naamSite" name="fields[naamSite]" />

    <button type="reset" style="float:left;">Reset</button>

    <button id="send-btn" type="submit">Opslaan</button>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Craft 3 / Guest Entries 2, you could pull this off without hacking Guest Entries by writing  a [module](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/module-guide.html) that listens to the [beforeSaveEntry](https://github.com/craftcms/guest-entries#the-beforesaveentry-event) event, and sets the `id` on the entry.

```php
use Craft;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\guestentries\controllers\SaveController;
use craft\guestentries\events\SaveEvent;
use yii\base\Event;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;

// ...

public function init()
{
    // ...

    Event::on(SaveController::class, SaveController::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ENTRY, function(SaveEvent $event) {
        $request = Craft::$app->getRequest();

        // Get the entry being edited
        $entryId = $request->getValidatedBodyParam('entryId');
        $currentEntry = Entry::find()->id($entryId)->anyStatus()->one();

        if (!$currentEntry) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('Invalid entry ID: ' . $entryId);
        }

        // Populate the guest submission with the entry ID, UID, and content ID
        $event->entry->id = $currentEntry->id;
        $event->entry->uid = $currentEntry->uid;
        $event->entry->contentId = $currentEntry->contentId;
    });
}
```

Then in your form, add an `entryId` input set to the hashed entry ID.

```twig
<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id|hash }}">
```

It’s important that you hash the entry ID and use `getValidatedBodyParam()` instead of `getBodyParam()` so users can’t repurpose the form to edit *any* entry on your site.

Comment: I tried this solution but it throws an "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry" error. I thought maybe it was because Craft 3.1 moved to UID's but changing "$event->entry->id" to "$event->entry->uid" and submitting based on that doesnt seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks to Robin for helping me fix this and updating the answer!

Comment: This was working beautifully until a Craft update and now it's freezing the site. Any idea why?

Comment: @fxfuture Can’t think of any reason it would stop working.

Answer (score 4):

I've figured it out

Go to GuestEntriesController.php and add this line of code on the 182nd line

```
$entry->id = craft()->request->getPost('entryId');
```

Then add an hidden input field with the id you wish to edit like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id }}">
```